# Random MCQ based on user selection

Tags: javascript

I have created a quiz which consist of 20 MCQ questions (in one page). The first thing is that the user have to select the number of question he/she wishes to attempt. here is my two radio button:

```
<p>Choose the number of question you want to attempt at a time</p>
    3 Question<input type="radio" name="radiobutton"  onClick="load('expert1.html')"/><br>
      OR<br>
    5 Question<input type="radio" name="radiobutton"  onClick="load('expert1.html')" />
```

when the user selects the first radio button only 3 question out of 20 must be display on a new page and after the user answered the 3 question it goes to another set of 3 question and same for second radio button.

my problem here is that am not able to make the 3 question or 5 question appear when the user selects the radio button.

my mcq question:

```
 var questions = new Array();

 var choices = new Array();

 var answers = new Array();

 var response = new Array();



  questions[0] = "1) RS-449/442-A/423-A is";

  choices[0] = new Array();

  choices[0][0] = "a set of physical layer standards developed by EIA and intended to replace RS-232-C.";

  choices[0][1] = "a check bit appended to an array of binary digits to make the sum of the all the binary digits";

  choices[0][2] = "a code in which each expression conforms to specific rules of construction, so that if certain errors occur in an expression the resulting expression will not conform to the rules of construction and thus the presence of the errors is detected";

  choices[0][3] = "the ratio of the number of data units in error to the total number of data units";

  answers[0] = choices[0][0];


  questions[1] = "2) CSMA (Carrier Sense Multiple Access) is";

  choices[1] = new Array();

  choices[1][0] = "a method of determining which device has access to the transmission medium at any time";

  choices[1][1] = "a method access control technique for multiple-access transmission media.";

  choices[1][2] = "network access standard for connecting stations to a circuit-switched network";

  choices[1][3] = "a very common bit-oriented data link protocol issued by ISO.";

  answers[1] = choices[1][1];


  questions[2] = "3) ARP (Address Resolution Protocol) is";

  choices[2] = new Array();

  choices[2][0] = "a TCP/IP protocol used to dynamically bind a high level IP Address to a low-level physical hardware address";

  choices[2][1] = "a TCP/IP high level protocol for transferring files from one machine to another";

  choices[2][2] = "a protocol used to monitor computers";

  choices[2][3] = "a protocol that handles error and control messages";

  answers[2] = choices[2][0];


  questions[3] = "4) When referring to instruction words, a mnemonic is:";

  choices[3] = new Array();

  choices[3][0] = "a short abbreviation for the operand address";

  choices[3][1] = "a short abbreviation for the operation to be performed";

  choices[3][2] = "a short abbreviation for the data word stored at the operand address";

  choices[3][3] = "shorthand for machine language";

  answers[3] = choices[3][1];


  questions[4] = "5) Which of the following statement is wrong ?";

  choices[4] = new Array();

  choices[4][0] = "mes = 123.56";

  choices[4][1] = "con = 'T' * 'A'";

  choices[4][2] = "this = 'T' * 20";

  choices[4][3] = "3 + a = b";

  answers[4] = choices[4][3];


  questions[5] = "6) What is the term used for describing the judgmental or commonsense part of problem solving?";

  choices[5] = new Array();

  choices[5][0] = "Heuristic.";

  choices[5][1] = "Critical";

  choices[5][2] = "Value based";

  choices[5][3] = "Analytical";

  answers[5] = choices[5][0];


  questions[6] = "7) What stage of the manufacturing process has been described as the mapping of function onto form?";

  choices[6] = new Array();

  choices[6][0] = "Design";

  choices[6][1] = "Distribution";

  choices[6][2] = "project management";

  choices[6][3] = "field service";

  answers[6] = choices[6][0];


  questions[7] = "8)  To invoke the LISP system, you must enter";

  choices[7] = new Array();

  choices[7][0] = "AI";

  choices[7][1] = "LISP";

  choices[7][2] = "CL (Common Lisp)";

  choices[7][3] = "both b and c";

  answers[7] = choices[7][3];


  questions[8] = "9) Ambiguity may be caused by:";

  choices[8] = new Array();

  choices[8][0] = "syntactic ambiguity";

  choices[8][1] = "multiple word meanings";

  choices[8][2] = "unclear antecedents";

  choices[8][3] = "All of the above";

  answers[8] = choices[8][3];


  questions[9] = "10) The functional difference between SR flip-flop and JK flip-flop is that";

  choices[9] = new Array();

  choices[9][0] = "JK flip-flop is faster than SR flip-flop";

  choices[9][1] = "JK flip-flop has a feed back path";

  choices[9][2] = "JK flip-flop accepts both inputs 1";

  choices[9][3] = "JK flip-flop does not require external clock";

  answers[9] = choices[4][0];


  questions[10] = "11) ASCII and EBCDIC differ in";

  choices[10] = new Array();

  choices[10][0] = "their efficiency in storing data";

  choices[10][1] = "the random and sequential access method";

  choices[10][2] = "the number of bytes used to store characters";

  choices[10][3] = " their collecting sequences";

  answers[10] = choices[10][3];


  questions[11] = "12) The time required for a pulse to decrease from 90 to 10 percent of its maximum value is known as";

  choices[11] = new Array();

  choices[11][0] = "rise time";

  choices[11][1] = "decay time";

  choices[11][2] = "binary level transition period";

  choices[11][3] = "propagation delay";

  answers[11] = choices[11][1];


  questions[12] = "13) A combinational logic circuit which is used when it is desired to send data from two or more source through a single transmission line is known as";

  choices[12] = new Array();

  choices[12][0] = "encoder";

  choices[12][1] = "decoder";

  choices[12][2] = "multiplexer";

  choices[12][3] = "demultiplexer";

  answers[12] = choices[12][2];


  questions[13] = "14) The m-bit parallel adder consists of:";

  choices[13] = new Array();

  choices[13][0] = "(m+1) full adders";

  choices[13][1] = "m/2 full adders";

  choices[13][2] = "m-1 full adders";

  choices[13][3] = "m full adders";

  answers[13] = choices[13][3];



  questions[14] = "15) Why are digital circuits easier to design than analog circuits?";

  choices[14] = new Array();

  choices[14][0] = "they do not control electricity precisely over a wide range";

  choices[14][1] = "they are made in the form of ICs";

  choices[14][2] = "all elements of digital circuit are from the same family";

  choices[14][3] = "they are smaller in size";

  answers[14] = choices[14][0];



  questions[15] = "16) The _____ is ultraviolet-light-erasable and electrically programmable. This allows the user to erase and store until programs and data are perfected.";

  choices[15] = new Array();

  choices[15][0] = "EPROM";

  choices[15][1] = "ROM";

  choices[15][2] = "PROM";

  choices[15][3] = " RAM";

  answers[15] = choices[15][0];



  questions[16] = "17) The logic 1 in positive logic system is represented by:";
  choices[16] = new Array();

  choices[16][0] = "zero voltage";

  choices[16][1] = " lower voltage level";

  choices[16][2] = "higher voltage level";

  choices[16][3] = "negative voltage";

  answers[16] = choices[16][2];



  questions[17] = "18) Which of the following TTL subfamily is the fastest";
  choices[17] = new Array();

  choices[17][0] = "standard TTL";

  choices[17][1] = "high-speed TTL";

  choices[17][2] = "schottky TTL";

  choices[17][3] = "low-speed TTL";

  answers[17] = choices[17][2];



  questions[18] = "19)  Cyclic codes are used in";

  choices[18] = new Array();

  choices[18][0] = " data transfer";

  choices[18][1] = "continuously varying signal representation";

  choices[18][2] = "arithmetic and logical computation";

  choices[18][3] = "All of the above";

  answers[18] = choices[18][1];



  questions[19] = "20) How many full and half-adders are required to add 16-bit numbers?";
  choices[19] = new Array();

  choices[19][0] = "8 half-adders, 8 full-adders";

  choices[19][1] = "1 half-adders, 15 full-adders";

  choices[19][2] = "16 half-adders, no full-adders";

  choices[19][3] = "4 half-adders, 12 full-adders";

  answers[19] = choices[19][1];
```

Answer (score 0):

First step: Use $_GET parameters

```
<p>Choose the number of question you want to attempt at a time</p>
    3 Question<input type="radio" name="radiobutton"  onClick="load('expert1.html?number=3')"/><br>
      OR<br>
    5 Question<input type="radio" name="radiobutton"  onClick="load('expert1.html?number=5')" />
```

Second Step: Read $_GET parameter and display questions accordingly

```
$numberOfQuestions = $_GET['number'];
// ...
```